# Vue Cli 3 browse to dist directory

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli-3

I have a Vue Cli 3 app which, when built, creates a bundle of web components in the "dist" directory.

I'm looking for a way to be able to browse the files within the "dist" directory when running `npm run serve`, which starts the webpack dev server.

When I do this now (i.e., something like browse to http://localhost:8083/dist/component.js), I'm simply presented with the index.html file found in the public directory.

How can I configure via the vue.config.js file the ability to have the devserver serve up files in the "dist" directory?

Comment: Do you want specifically your current `devServer` to serve `/dist` folder or you are looking for a way to serve these static files to browser your production application?

Comment: Looking for a way to have my devServer serve up the static /dist folder for local testing. 

We will deploy the /dist folder to an actual web server for production purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`devServer` is intended to provide development environment with configurations to apply certain loaders, plugins, etc. What you are looking for is a way to serve locally hosted files as a working application. These are two different purposes and I would not recommend adjusting `devServer` config for such purpose.

There are easy ways to serve static files on local machine.
One of the simplest is to use [live-server](https://github.com/tapio/live-server), [serve](https://github.com/zeit/serve) or similar.

In order for it to work with `live-server` just few steps are required:

1) Install

```
npm install -g live-server
```

2) In terminal navigate to the folder where static files are located (e.g. `project-folder/dist/`

3) Run `live-server` command.

This will open a browser tab with `index.html` as an entry point and will simulate a webserver on a local machine. There are many more options available in [docs](https://github.com/tapio/live-server#usage-from-command-line).

But this will serve the purpose and will not interfere with `devServer` purpose.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping there was a way to do this with devServer. I actually ended up creating my own server.js file which creates an http/https server using express.

Comment: Thanks. I prefer live-server because it has more options to customize. I had trouble finding options for 'cors' and 'proxy' in 'serve' package.